# Cross Domain Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, ajax, silverlight, basic-authentication

I'm trying to do cross domain basic authentication in Silverlight on the browser stack to a web server, I have access to the computer, although I do not have access to the code or how it's being hosted. Whenever I try to the following code I get a `NotSupportedException`,

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.example.com", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

I also tried the following with ajax but it turns into an OPTIONS 1.1 request,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com",
    global: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
    },
});
```

If I change `http://www.example.com` to not be a cross domain call both code samples work. Is it possible to a cross domain basic authentication in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at he following link about [making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries in silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I've been using basic auth for years now but I've been using it using

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

NOTE: It turns out that Silverlight provides HTTP handling in both the Browser and Client stack.By default Silverlight uses the Browser for HTTP handling. The only problem with this is that Browser HTTP Handling only supports GET and POST request methods.

By doing this you should be able to access RESTful service that allow PUT and DELETE Http methods.

I've been able to use Bearer (JWT) Authentication via this method as well.

Hope this helps.